# Query string for JIRA API GET

Tags: python, python-requests, jira-rest-api

This page [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-issue-picker-get) shows how to use Python `requests` to call a `GET` to search for a list of issues in JIRA.

```
# This code sample uses the 'requests' library:
# http://docs.python-requests.org
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/picker"

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")

headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json"
}

query = {
  'query': 'query'
}

response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   params=query,
   auth=auth
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

However, the sample code above uses a generic `query` text. How would I construct a query to search for all issues with a specific assignee. Below is the JSON structure of a JIRA request response for one issue for my case:

```
{'customfield_100': [],
 'customfield_1021': None,
 ...
 'assignee':{
     'self': 'https://.....',
     'accountId': 'xxxxxxx',
     'displayName': 'Bob Bobbette',
      ....
  }

}
```